# Is there a difference between 'eventually' and 'in the future'?

Tags: word-choice, differences, word-usage, future

I was at a yoga class and the instructor said something about how a posture will 'eventually or in the future allow you to roll your spine out.'.

And then I wanted to know, is there a difference between the two phrases?

Is there more certainty in one, or maybe one implies a ''sooner'' time?

Comment: It almost sounds like the instructor was correcting their comment on the fly, like maybe they started to say "eventually" but immediately changed it to "in the future".  That is pure conjecture, of course, since only the instructor can confirm what was meant by that phrase.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Yes. In speech we don't get to hit an edit button and trim out things like that.

Answer (score 2):

In this context the instructor's use of two phrases instead of one is needless verbiage; the meaning is similar enough that either one alone will do.  However, common synonyms of *[eventually](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eventually#Adverb)* include     *at last,    finally,    ultimately,  in the end*, all suggestive of later-rather-than-sooner, unlike *[future](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/future#Noun)*, which makes no commitment about when something will happen.

Comment: I would also add that there is a difference in that the wait involved in an event that occurs "eventually" has a negative connotation (shared with finally and at last) in that the speaker is begrudgingly waiting for it to happen; he/she doesn't want to wait that long! "In the future" has a more neutral or positive tone, depending on the context – either a statement of fact, or a sort of a giddy "I can't wait for this to happen!"

The phrase "eventually or in the future" seems ridiculous.